# Create a Code Signing Certificate for electron and add it to nsis installer

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder, self-signed

I am new to electron and I am getting an `unknown publisher` error each time I deploy my application on a PC. I have tried disabling User Account Control Settings but it only worked on some windows 10, plus it is not a good way to solve the problem.

And after some research, I found that I can create a `self-signed certificate` using [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/cli):

```
electron-builder create-self-signed-cert -p Name
```

When I am running this cmd I am getting a `.pfx` file certificate. Now, following [this documentation](https://www.electron.build/code-signing#windows), I know that to sign the app on the build server I need to set `CSC_LINK`, `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD`. (how do I set the CSC link and key password? do I add them inside my package.json?)

First I need to `export the certificate` (do I just upload the certificate to a server?)

Second I need to `encode file to base64` (after I uploaded the certificate do I encode it? from .pfx to txt?)

Moreover, is it better to attach the `.pfx` file to the `nsis` installer? or just use a server to handle this job?

I am so lost any help would go a long way. thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 3):

Open your windows powershell(open start and type windows powershell) and enter these commands, you will be able to export the certificate to C:\Cert folder and then use it inside your package.json file.

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName "www.domain.com" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Type CodeSigningCert -Subject “Example Code Signing Certificate”

$CertPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "my_password" -Force -AsPlainText

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "cert:\CurrentUser\My$($cert.Thumbprint)" -FilePath "C:\Cert$certificate.pfx" -Password $CertPassword

Your win inside package.json should look like this

```
"win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "publisherName":"microsoft",
      "certificateFile": "./certificate.pfx",
      "certificatePassword": "my_password"
    },
```

Put the certificate file in your project folder and give its path to certificateFile.
**NOTE: Use it for development purpose only as it is not an optimal way.**

Mentions: https://sectigostore.com/page/how-do-i-generate-a-self-signed-code-signing-certificate