# How to create correctly a self signed certificate for vue-electron app

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder, self-signed

I have this configuration in package.json file for my electron vue app

```json
{
  "name": "mailer-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service electron:build create-self-signed-cert --p always",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/local-auth": "^2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "easy-template-x": "^3.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^105.0.0",
    "node-excel-stream": "^1.2.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "electron": "24.3.0",
    "electron-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^3.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

I need to generate a self signed certificate to avoid the warning during the installation on our company machines. I've noticed thet when I run the `npm run build` command, the certificate will be not generated. I've searche da bit and I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388954/create-a-code-signing-certificate-for-electron-and-add-it-to-nsis-installer), that helped me a bit, but didn't solved my problem. How I can generate the certificate and sign the app correctly?